# Power Apps Edit Form - Edits Change All Items in the List

Tags: excel, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula, powerapps-selected-items

I am making a power app for my company. I need to create a list of each employee within a department and a list of all training topics they need to complete, and have either a yes or no in each training item. I created an excel workbook with a table for each person and their training. I used that as the data connection and made two screens for the app. The first one used the list template and displays each employee. There is an edit button in each card that navigates to the training edit screen. That screen is an edit form that shows a yes or no in each text box. The user can make changes and view the completion status of each training topic.

It works great for one single person. The issue I am having however, is that changes made to one person reflect on all the employees. If I enter "no" for one training topic, it will update that for all the employees. What I am asking is if there is a way to make sure that each edit form only reflects the selected item? I passed ThisItem into the edit screen when you click the button on the personnel screen.

The formula I used on select of the edit button on the personnel screen is this:

Navigate(TrainingEdit, None, {SelectedItem: ThisItem})

When I submit the edit form on the edit screen, the formula on select of the submit button is this:

SubmitForm(TrainingForm); Navigate(PersonnelList)

Once again, the issue I am having is that the changes made to one employee reflect on all of them in the list. I just need to figure out a way to make the edit forms separate for each of the employees. Any feedback is greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: On your TrainingForm, what is the "Item" property currently set to?

Comment: @JBerg The Item property says Last(TrainingChecklist) <- the TrainingChecklist is the name of the table in the excel workbook. Is that the root of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want the Item() property of your TrainingForm to be the Gallery.Selected of the first screen.